# How do you set autofocus on a ZF2 form element?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How do you set the autofocus attribute on a ZF2 form element?

I presume we can use either setter methods or options in a factory array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding an element in the construct method, you may use

```
'autofocus'=>'true'
```

Inside the attributes of that element. Here I pase the code of my "email" element:

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'email', 
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Email',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Email:'
            ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'type' => 'email', 
            'required' => true, 
            'placeholder' => 'myaccount@domain.com', 
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'tabindex' =>'1',
            'id'=>'email',
            'autofocus'=>'true'
            )
        ));
```

Comment: From that I also deduce that we can do $element->setAttribute('autofocus', true);

Comment: I have tried this directly into the 'view' and it's working: $emailElement = $this->form1->get('email');$emailElement->setAttribute("autofocus","true");